# Cancel/Transfer Registration Link in Contact Dashboard

Tags: civievent

I know that I can select "Allow self-service cancellation or transfer?" when I create an event which includes a link in the email to the user. However, this link doesn't show in the user dashboard with the event detail. Is it meant to? How can I include this link in the dashboard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["My Registered Events" listing (with cancellation option) for user dashboard page](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37836/my-registered-events-listing-with-cancellation-option-for-user-dashboard-pag)

Comment: Hi Sarah - I wrote an extension to allow self-service cancellation/transfer from the dashboard!  See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37836/my-registered-events-listing-with-cancellation-option-for-user-dashboard-pag.

Answer (score 3):

This feature makes sense, but doesn't currently exist.  However, I created [an issue in the CiviCRM issue tracker](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/event/-/issues/26) for this exact feature.

I have a client who wants this, but I think they're going to run out of money before we can do it unfortunately.

The good news is that they DID fund the biggest part of this - until two months ago, the self-service cancel/transfer code was only accessible from the self-service/cancel page.  They funded me to [move the code to a central location](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16615).  In the next couple of weeks, I intend to clean this code up further, at which point it should be under an hour's work to add self-service transfer/cancellation links to the user dashboard.

Comment: I will chip in to help you across the line with this if that helps. hopefully others might too

Comment: Thanks for the offer @petednz-fuzion.  Let's see where I'm at after I clean up the code.  I could swear I wrote a patch for my client to give this functionality, which may be adaptable with a negligible amount of work.