# "My Registered Events" listing (with cancellation option) for user dashboard page

Tags: civievent, user-dashboard

I've searched and researched and come up empty - is it possible to present a dashboard (summary) view of the events that a person has registered for, along with the ability to easily cancel from any of the listed events? It seems like a very useful thing to have but I'm coming up empty when trying to find any mention of doing so with CiviCRM.

Answer (score 4):

The feature you're referring to is called the "Contact Dashboard", and it's accessible from https://yoursite.org/civicrm/user in Drupal and Backdrop, not sure about WordPress.

You can add/remove sections from it at **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Display Preferences**.

It doesn't allow self-service cancellations, but I wrote the extension "[Event Self Service from User Dashboard](https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-self-service-user-dashboard) "to deal with this specific scenario.

Comment: For WordPress, I discovered the shortcode [civicrm component="user-dashboard" hijack="0"], and also a direct URL for the contact dashboard at mydomain.org/civicrm/user/?reset=1.

Comment: That's great! For my part - I got an email this morning pushing the "self-service cancellation" option to the top of my client's wishlist.  Watch this space, I'll try to have this done within a week.

Comment: Self-service cancellations would be very useful. I don't understand why cancellation links (which are created in registration confirmation emails by Civi) are only made available once. By that i mean, there isn't a way that I can find to include a cancellation link in an event reminder email.

Comment: It's a limit of the old token processor that tokens can only be created based on contact ID.  There's a new token processor, and it's used in some areas (e.g. scheduled reminders) but not everywhere yet.  The event reminder emails are built using Smarty and don't have this limitation.  The "cancel from dashboard" extension I'm writing was actually a fallback plan because cancellation URLs can't be generated without Smarty.

Comment: OK, I wrote the extension!  It's only received light testing, so let me know if you run into trouble.  I edited the answer above to include a URL to the extension page.

Comment: Hey Eric - note there's a bug in CiviCRM 5.29 and 5.30.0 that causes events not to appear on the contact dashboard unless you're an administrator.  This should be fixed in CiviCRM 5.31+ and probably even 5.30.1.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I am trying it out and see the Cancel/Transfer button on the dashboard, great! One thing though, it also appears next to past events. Would you revise the logic, or is that purposeful?

Comment: @EricSwanzey I can check that out.  Can you confirm a) how many hours before the event you're cutting off cancellation, b) what happens if you click the cancel/transfer button?

Comment: The registration cutoffs are usually 1 hour before an event. When cancelling an event as a registrant, the cancellation fails with a "getFieldValue failed" error. Trying to track that down...

Comment: @EricSwanzey it sounds like the problem might be with the event cancellation logic in core - which I rewrote in part to accommodate this extension.  Or maybe a different extension? I would open a new question for the "getFieldValue failed" error, and be sure to include the [full debugging message and the backtrace](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/troubleshooting/#debugging).